# Spring web flow end state, want to go and edit a previous error?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

We have a web flow, and only at the very end can we sometimes tell that there was an error processing a transaction. We want to add functionality to the end of the flow, currently a natural end-state, that lets the user click an edit button to go back to, say, step 2 of the flow to re-enter some details.

Can this be done? The only way I see is to make my current-end state just a regular view-state with a transition to state 2 on the click of a button, but the end-state makes a lot of sense since we want to clear the details of the transaction.

Can anyone help me line up the thinking here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a decision state just before the end state would work OK. A test can be made to see if the transaction went OK, and depending on that either go to the end state or back to a previous view:

```
<decision-state id="checkIfTransactionOK">
    <if test="service.isTransactionFailed()" then="previousViewState" else="endState" />
</decision-state>
```

Comment: This is close, but isn't exactly what I want to know if possible. Essentially this answer is what I tried but it doesn't work for what my spec says. We want to show an error page if the transaction failed, with a button to allow the user to go back to a previous view to edit if they want. But I'm not sure this is possible, the end-state triggers the session to be killed, http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/pr5/api/org/springframework/webflow/EndState.html

So I guess I have to think about not having a place for a failure page, do this kind of transition, and show the error there?..tough

Comment: you mean to recover from a database transaction failure, or from a business transaction failure due to some validation error?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're addressing. The fact is we can detect if transaction died, and we want to give the user the option, key word, of going back and editing their input to try again, but it should be in the same flow context because we want to carry over the details so they can edit those pieces without re-entering from scratch...

Comment: could you put on the question how can you detect that the transaction died (the code),  and the  error you get (full stacktrace if possible)?